# Manually set nil to swift object to avoid retain cycle?

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I've been profiling one of the apps written in swift lately and been very frustrated with ARC in general, coming from languages where mark-and-sweep GC is the norm.

Especially, `UIViewController`s that are **very** complex with lots of dependencies to other `class`, I've been failing to get ARC working properly. But I know that simply setting retained objects to `nil` gets them deallocated without dabbling with ARC.

This is especially true for `UIViewController` where I can set `nil` to all retained objects in `viewDidDisappear` or the similar.

Is this kind of practice considered bad / harmful? Should I just try harder to get ARC working?

edit: By not working, I mostly mean to break `Strong Reference Cycle`, which becomes quite unwieldy when there are multiple hierarchies of dependencies.

edit: FYI, I'm aware that using `weak` / `unowned` in declaration / capture list breaks the retain cycle. I'm asking in cases where using those norms become unwieldy due to the complexity of an object or, rather, the retain cycle of an object.

Comment: I removed the Objective-C tag because your question title is about setting a Swift object to `nil`. Objective-C has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've been failing to get ARC working properly"? Do you mean that things are being retained when you don't expect them to?

Comment: @michaelrccurtis I edited the question. I meant to refer breaking `Strong Reference Cycle`

Comment: If you have a problem with reference cycles then you need to understand your app's object graph and implement weak references. Example: `delegate`s should usually be weak. Then ARC will automatically deallocate the objects as soon as the last strong reference goes away.

Comment: @RoboticCat sorry for being not clear in the question. I've edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should take a look at your class structure - basically work out which classes should "own" certain properties (i.e. strong reference) and who just needs to be referencing them when they are available (i.e. weak references).

I think it is well worth thinking about this, as it will probably streamline your code. It will also give you an opportunity to really think about privilege - do all these other classes really need access to these objects etc.

The real problem with setting things to nil is that you have to be sure that you are catching all strong reference cycles and that, ultimately, you are not benefiting from ARC making your life easier.

Comment: yeah i know it's bad to fight the system but man, figuring out whether to put capture list for every single closure is quite an overhead to pay...

Answer (score 0):

> Try deinit Method its wright way I guess

```
 deinit{
    person = nil
}
```

Comment: I edited the question. `deinit` will never get called with retain cycle.